# Calculate the closest Point to the center of the image

Tags: c#

**The code does this:**

1. Find the squares
2. Find the closest centroid to the center of the image ( by distance )
3. Draw the closest square centroid (purple) on the image

**PROBLEM:**
My problem is that it's drawing on every square so it's not finding the closest centroid. **It draws the purple circle on both squares**

**CODE:**

```
double distancia_menor = double.MaxValue;

using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage()) //aloca espaço na memoria
{
    //Procura contornos 
    for (Contour<System.Drawing.Point> contours = frame_drone_canny.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_TREE, storage); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
    {
        Contour<System.Drawing.Point> currentContour = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.05, storage); //AproxContour                       

        if (currentContour.Area > 3300/*currentContour.Area >= area_contornos_min.Value && currentContour.Area <= area_contornos_max.Value*/) //se a area estiver dentro dos valores das trackbars
        {
            if (currentContour.Total == 4) //se for retangulo/quadrado
            {
                retangular = true;

                pontos = currentContour.ToArray(); //pontos para array
                LineSegment2D[] edges = PointCollection.PolyLine(pontos, true);

                for (int i = 0; i < edges.Length; i++)
                {
                    double angle = Math.Abs(edges[(i + 1) % edges.Length].GetExteriorAngleDegree(edges[i]));

                    if (angle < 75 || angle > 105) //Limitação do angulo para determinar se é quadrado ou nao
                    {
                        retangular = false; //não é quadrado
                        centroid = new Point(0, 0);
                        //posicao_atual = new PointF(0, 0);
                    }
                }

                if (retangular)
                {
                    centroid.X = (int)currentContour.GetMoments().GravityCenter.x;
                    centroid.Y = (int)currentContour.GetMoments().GravityCenter.y;

                    double c = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(centroid.X - tamanho_imagem.X / 2, 2) + Math.Pow(centroid.X - tamanho_imagem.X / 2, 2)));
                    Debug.WriteLine(c);
                }
            }

            if (c < distancia_menor)
            {
                distancia_menor = c;
                centroid_mais_proximo = new PointF(centroid.X, centroid.Y);

                frame_drone_copia.Draw(new CircleF(new System.Drawing.PointF(centroid_mais_proximo.X, centroid_mais_proximo.Y), 1), new Bgr(Color.Purple), 17);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**IMAGE:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're testing both shapes, and drawing the purple circle as you update the min. If the loop happens to test the closest one first, it will draw only the right one. But since it happens to test the farther one first, it draws two circles.

Change your code to find the closest point inside the loop and move the code to draw the purple circle outside the loop.